# Custom Keyboard Advice

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios5, ios4

I am trying to make a custom keyboard like the one below, where they add that row of keys. Can you point me in some sort of direction code wise. I have already read the documentation. Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Here's a useful tutorial:http://gabriel-tips.blogspot.com/2011/05/input-accessory-view-how-to-add-extra.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its not a custom keyboard but a `UIView` subclass that got attached to the keyboard. You can do this by setting the `inputAccessoryView` property of your `UITextView` to your view containing the extra buttons.